# The map $f(u+v) = u - v$ is an isomorphism on a direct product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a nontrivial vector space, and $U,W \neq \{0\}$ subspaces of $V$.

Suppose that $V=U \oplus W$. Now I am wondering how to show that the map $f(u+w) = u - w$ is an isomorphism on V, because I haven't seen this kind of sum as function argument before in this context.

My first guess was to try to show that $f((a+b) + (c+d)) = (a+b) - (c+d) = f(a+b) + f(c+d)$. This however is not true. How would one show that this map is indeed an isomorphism?

Comment: Not a big fan of that notation.  Maybe it would be clearer if you wrote $f(u,w)=(u,-w)$.

Comment: @lulu can you elaborate on why these notations are equal?

Comment: They aren't equal; mine is good and the one you used is bad.  Your notation is bad because it conflates vector addition with the direct sum.  You can't add $\vec u$ and $\vec w$ in the vector sense as they aren't in the same vector space.

Comment: To stress:  in a single vector space $V$ it makes no sense to write $f(\vec {v_1}+\vec {v_2})=\vec {v_1}-\vec {v_2}$.  After all, $\vec v= \vec 0 +\vec v=\vec v+\vec 0$ so you would get $f(\vec v)=-\vec v = \vec v$ which is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks. However, the notation here wasn't my choice, it was given

Comment: Sure, I understand that.  But, using the description I gave, can you see why this map is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annoying thing with direct sums is that there are two ways of introducing it: internal and external (which is what's being mentioned in the comments). In your case, we're talking about an internal direct sum.

So, the fact that $U,W$ are vector subspaces of $V$ such that $U\cap W=\{0\}$ and $V=U+W$ means that the mapping $\alpha:U\times W\to V$, $\alpha(u,w):= u+w$ is a linear isomorphism ($U\cap W=\{0\}$ gives injectivity, and $V=U+W$ gives surjectivity by definition). This isomorphism identifies $V=U\oplus_{\text{internal}}W$ with $U\times W=U\oplus_{\text{external}}W$.

Now, consider the mapping $\phi:U\times W\to U\times W$ defined as $\phi(u,w):=(u,-w)$. You say that you're confused by the sum argument notation. Well, the definition of $f:V\to V$ is
\begin{align}
f:= \alpha\circ \phi\circ \alpha^{-1}
\end{align}

In other words, for each $v\in V$, **there exist unique** $u\in U,w\in W$ such that $v=u+w$. So, $\alpha^{-1}(v)=(u,w)$, so performing the composition, we get
\begin{align}
f(v)&=(\alpha\circ \phi\circ \alpha^{-1})(v)=\alpha(\phi(u,w))=\alpha(u,-w)=u+(-w)=u-w
\end{align}
Hence, rather than explicitly introducing the notation for the isomorphism $\alpha$, your problem simply states the definition of $f$ as $f(u+w):=u-w$ where $u\in U,w\in W$.

---

As for proving that $f$ is indeed an isomorphism though, the more "abstract" definition $f=\alpha\circ \phi\circ \alpha^{-1}$ makes it almost obvious (why?)

Comment: Could be obvious, but I still don't get why this is an isomorphism. It's obviously bijective, but that the other laws are fulfilled I can't see at first glance. could you elaborate? can I simply do $f(a+b)=f(a) +f(b)$, use the definition and arrive at an answer, or is this completely wrong?

Comment: It is a triple composition of linear isomorphisms

Comment: If we look at a simple example of this, like $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $U$ be the "horizontal axis" and $W$ the "vertical axis", would $f$ simply flip $\mathbb{R}^2$ along the horizontal axis?

Comment: @AlSneed yes exactly.

Comment: I am sorry to ask, but one last question. You assumed that the map was a linear homomorphism, but that remains to be shown. If we wanted to show this for $\phi$, would we have to show that $\phi((u,v)+(u',v')) = \phi(u,v) + \phi(u',v')$? I never did this kind of stuff with two arguments, I literally have no clue.

Comment: @AlSneed Indeed I skipped the verification that $\phi$ is linear. I skipped it because it is a trivial definition checking exercise. You have to show $\phi((u,w)+ (u',w'))=\phi(u,w)+\phi(u',w')$ and that $\phi(c(u,w))=c\phi(u,w)$. Their proofs is an almost immediate application of the definition of addition and scalar multiplication in the product space $U\times W$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133018/discussion-between-al-sneed-and-peek-a-boo).